# db2 stored procedure to create a select query dynamically

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am new to IBM db2 stored procedure, what I am trying to do is to get the values of a column from a table and build a select query based on these values, this is what I have tried, not sure how to proceed

```
CREATE TYPE currencySymbols AS VARCHAR(20) ARRAY[100]@

CREATE PROCEDURE ins_curr_ano(IN crsymbol VARCHAR(20), IN cost1 integer, IN cost2 integer, IN teirId integer) 
BEGIN
DECLARE currencies currencySymbols;
DECLARE maxCount INTEGER DEAFULT 0;

set currencies = ARRAY[SELECT distinct(CURR_SYMBOL) as currencySymbols FROM CURRENCY_MAPPING];

set maxCount = CARDINALITY(currencies);

for i in 1..maxCount loop
     dbms_output.put_line(i);
end loop;

END@
```

Below is the error I am getting:

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "loop" was found following "for i in
1..maxCount".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".  LINE NUMBER=13.
SQLSTATE=42601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `for ... loop` statement in your code has PL/SQL syntax, while everything else has DB2 SQL PL syntax. You cannot mix the two in the same routine.